# Having trouble clearing canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The problem I'm having is that the lines are not properly clearing from the canvas. Not quite sure as to why. I've looked into the issue for quite awhile. Here's some of the code:

function that handles the creation of line segments

```
var ui=
{   
    clear:function()
    {
        gsx.clearRect(0,0,window.gsW,window.gsH);
    },
    drawCharacterRays:function()
    {
        for(z=0;z<wallJoints.length;z++)
        {
            originx=(gsW/2);
            originy=(gsH/2);
            gsx.strokeStyle='#ff0000';
            gsx.beginPath();
            gsx.moveTo(originx,originy);
            gsx.lineTo(wallJoints[z][0],wallJoints[z][1]);
            gsx.closePath();
            gsx.stroke();
        }

    }
}
```

And some extra code to show the order at which functions are called:

```
function engine()
{   
    ui.clear();

    gsx.fillStyle="#ffffff";
    gsx.fillRect((gsW-characterW)-window.x,(gsH-characterH)-window.y,mapW,mapH);

    ui.drawMap(curLevel,
    [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]);

    ui.drawCharacterRays();
    ui.drawCharacter();
    ui.drawStaminaBar();
    ui.drawHealthBar();
}
```

I'd be happy to drop more code if needed, but be warned... There's a lot...

Saved myself some time and made a functional version in a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/cAv63

Comment: I feel better if you post some more code buddy. especially I don't know what is the window.gsh and window.gsw? I know its canvas height but want to see how you defined. and want to see your html too.. how many canvas elements did you used?

Comment: Added a fiddle to properly illustrate the issue.

Comment: Maybe a clue: Your wallJoints.length is rapidly increasing into the tens of thousands.

Comment: ...Actually.. that might be it xD

Comment: Yep. Feel free to submit that as an answer and I'll gladly accept it.